# While Installing Oracle database 11g Checking For Oracle XE Service instance FAILED what should I do

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-xe

I am getting this error while installing the Oracle database 11g
it giving me an error Checking For Oracle XE Service instance FAILED

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OracleServiceXE is probably a remnant of a previous install.  You'll need to remove it using the `sc` command:

```
sc delete OracleServiceXE
```

Make sure you run the command as Administrator.

Answer (score -1):

```
STEP1: Start -> run (services.msc) -> Services => Stop OracleServiceXE (if running)
```

[image]

```
  STEP2: Start -> CMD (run as admin) -> sc delete OracleServiceXE

  Now RESTART your System
```